# slicing and array into a hasn value

Tags: perl, hash, slice

What I was trying to do was combine elements[1..3] into a single array, and then make the has out of that. Then sort by keys and print out the whole thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %hash ; 
while ( <> ) {
    @elements = split /,/, $_;
    @slice_elements = @elements[1..3] ;
    if ($elements[0] ne '' ) {
        $hash{ $elements[0] } = $slice_elements[0];
    }
}

foreach $key (sort keys %hash ) {
       print "$key; $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

This is what I get when I print this out  -

```
casper_mint@casper-mint-dell /tmp $ /tmp/dke /tmp/File1.csv


060001.926941; TOT
060002.029434; RTP
060002.029568; RTP
060002.126895; UL
060002.229327; RDS/A
060002.312512; EON
060002.429382; RTP
060002.585408; BCS
060002.629333; LYG
060002.712240; HBC
```

This is waht I want the elements of the array  - element[0] is the key and element[1..3] in the value

```
060001.926941,TOT,86.26,86.48
060002.029434,RTP,310.0,310.66
060002.029568,RTP,310.0,310.74
060002.126895,UL,34.06,34.14
060002.229327,RDS/A,84.47,84.72
060002.312512,EON,56.88,57.04
060002.429382,RTP,310.08,310.77
060002.585408,BCS,58.96,59.06
060002.629333,LYG,46.13,46.41
060002.712240,HBC,93.06,93.23
```

Answer (score 2):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.

What you need is to create a new anonymous array `[ ]` as the value to your hash.  Then [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) the values when displaying the results:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @elements = split /,/, $_;
    if ($elements[0] ne '' ) {
        $hash{ $elements[0] } = [@elements[1..3]];
    }
}

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash ) {
    print join(',', $key, @{$hash{$key}}) . "\n";
}
```

Of course, if your data really is fixed width like that, and you're not actually doing anything with the values, there actually is no need to `split` and `join`.  The following would do the same thing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print sort <>;
```

Comment: nitpicking, `my ($key, @elements) = split /,/;`